# Custom BoundField doesn't preserve data between PostBacks with added LiteralControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview, databound

I've created a custom `BoundField` for use with a `DetailsView` in *Edit* and *Insert* modes to utilize Twitter Bootstrap.

The control works fine, except when I add in extra `LiteralControl`s to surround the `TextBox` with some HTML during *InitializeDataCell(...)*. Code related to this toward the end.

The HTML generated is below seems to be identical to what is generated with a `TemplateField`. But when I fire an *Update*, anytime it adds the extra *div* / *span* seen here, the value in the `TextBox` is blank upon *PostBack*.

```
<div class="input-prepend">
    <span class="add-on">$</span>
    <input name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContent$pi$dvPackage$tbPrice" type="text" value="0" size="5" id="MainContent_MainContent_pi_dvPackage_tbPrice" title="Price">
</div>
```

Here is some examples of what I'm doing within the front ASP.NET code and what HTML is generated.

**Doesn't work - custom field**
Value inside text box is unset after submitting via *Update* command, ONLY when I add the *input-append* and *add-on* part.

*Field inside DetailsView*

```
<my:ValidationField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" TextPrepend="$" />
```

*HTML generated*

```
<td>
    <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on">$</span>
        <input name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContent$pi$dvPackage$tbPrice" type="text" value="0" size="5" id="MainContent_MainContent_pi_dvPackage_tbPrice" title="Price">
    </div>
</td>
```

**Does work - normal TemplateField**
Works fine

*Field inside DetailsView*

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on">$</span>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbCost" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Cost") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

*HTML generated - identical to what is above*

```
<td>
    <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on">$</span>
        <input name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContent$pi$dvPackage$tbPrice" type="text" value="0" size="5" id="MainContent_MainContent_pi_dvPackage_tbPrice" title="Price">
    </div>
</td>
```

**Does work - HTML generated with custom field**
Value inside text box is correctly submitted via *Update* command when I don't add the *TextPrepend* field.

*Field inside DetailsView*

```
<my:ValidationField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" />
```

*HTML generated without extra span / div*

```
<td>
    <input name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContent$pi$dvPackage$tbPrice" type="text" value="0" size="5" id="MainContent_MainContent_pi_dvPackage_tbPrice" title="Price">
</td>
```

**InitializeDataCell** parts related to this code creation

I believe this is due to something with the *InitializeDataCell(...)* implementation.

```
protected override void InitializeDataCell(DataControlFieldCell cell, DataControlRowState rowState)
{
    base.InitializeDataCell(cell, rowState);

    // Find the text box to validate
    TextBox text = FindTextBox(cell);

    if (text != null)
    {
        text.ID = "tb" + DataField;
        text.MaxLength = MaxLength;
        text.TextMode = TextMode;
        text.Text = DataField;

        string cellCss = string.Empty;
        bool prepend = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.TextPrepend);
        bool append = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.TextAppend);
        bool addon = prepend || append;

        if (prepend == true)
            cellCss = this.ConcatenateCss(cellCss, "input-prepend");

        if (append == true)
            cellCss = this.ConcatenateCss(cellCss, "input-append");

        if (addon == true)
        {
            int textIndex = cell.Controls.IndexOf(text);

            Literal container = new Literal();
            container.Text = "<div class=\"" + cellCss + "\">";
            cell.Controls.AddAt(textIndex, container);
        }

        if (prepend == true)
        {
            int textIndex = cell.Controls.IndexOf(text);

            Literal units = new Literal();
            units.Text = "<span class=\"add-on\">" + this.Prepend() + "</span>";
            cell.Controls.AddAt(textIndex, units);
        }

        if (append == true)
        {
            Literal units = new Literal();
            units.Text = "<span class=\"add-on\">" + this.Append() + "</span>";
            cell.Controls.Add(units);
        }

        if (addon == true)
        {
            Literal container = new Literal();
            container.Text = "</div>";
            cell.Controls.Add(container);
        }
    }
}
```

**Entire code** in case it's useful to anyone trying to use Twitter Bootstrap, or if my code is wrong elsewhere.

```
public class ValidationField : BoundField
{
    #region Properties
    public virtual string EditTextCssClass
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)(ViewState["EditTextCssClass"] ?? string.Empty);
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["EditTextCssClass"] = value;
            OnFieldChanged();
        }
    }

    public virtual ValidatorDisplay ErrorDisplay
    {
        get
        {
            return (ValidatorDisplay)(ViewState["ErrorDisplay"] ?? ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic);
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["ErrorDisplay"] = value;
            OnFieldChanged();
        }
    }

    public virtual string ErrorMessage
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)(ViewState["ErrorMessage"] ?? "Invalid value entered");
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["ErrorMessage"] = value;
            OnFieldChanged();
        }
    }

    public virtual string HelpText
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)(ViewState["HelpText"] ?? string.Empty);
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["HelpText"] = value;
            OnFieldChanged();
        }
    }

    public virtual TwitterBootstrap.WebControls.TextBox.HelpTextDisplayMode HelpDisplay
    {
        get
        {
            return (TwitterBootstrap.WebControls.TextBox.HelpTextDisplayMode)(ViewState["HelpDisplay"] ?? TwitterBootstrap.WebControls.TextBox.HelpTextDisplayMode.Block);
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["HelpDisplay"] = value;
            OnFieldChanged();
        }
    }

    public virtual int MaxLength
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)(ViewState["MaxLength"] ?? 0);
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["MaxLength"] = value;
            OnFieldChanged();
        }
    }

    public virtual string PlaceHolder
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)(ViewState["PlaceHolder"] ?? string.Empty);
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["PlaceHolder"] = value;
            OnFieldChanged();
        }
    }

    public virtual bool Required
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)(ViewState["Required"] ?? false);
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["Required"] = value;
            OnFieldChanged();
        }
    }

    public virtual TextBoxMode TextMode
    {
        get
        {
            return (TextBoxMode)(ViewState["TextMode"] ?? TextBoxMode.SingleLine);
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["TextMode"] = value;
            OnFieldChanged();
        }
    }

    public virtual string ValidationExpression
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)(ViewState["ValidationExpression"] ?? string.Empty);
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["ValidationExpression"] = value;
            OnFieldChanged();
        }
    }

    public virtual string ValidationGroup
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)(ViewState["ValidationGroup"] ?? string.Empty);
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["ValidationGroup"] = value;
            OnFieldChanged();
        }
    }

    public virtual string TextAppend
    {
        get
        {
            object value = ViewState["TextAppend"];
            if (value != null)
                return value.ToString();

            return string.Empty;
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["TextAppend"] = value;
            OnFieldChanged();
        }
    }

    public virtual string TextPrepend
    {
        get
        {
            object value = ViewState["TextPrepend"];
            if (value != null)
                return value.ToString();

            return string.Empty;
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["TextPrepend"] = value;
            OnFieldChanged();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public ValidationField()
    {

    }

    protected override DataControlField CreateField()
    {
        return new ValidationField();
    }

    protected override void InitializeDataCell(DataControlFieldCell cell, DataControlRowState rowState)
    {
        base.InitializeDataCell(cell, rowState);

        // Find the text box to validate
        TextBox text = FindTextBox(cell);

        if (text != null)
        {
            text.ID = "tb" + DataField;
            text.MaxLength = MaxLength;
            text.TextMode = TextMode;
            text.CssClass = EditTextCssClass;
            text.Text = DataField;

            if (PlaceHolder != string.Empty)
                text.Attributes.Add("placeholder", PlaceHolder);

            string cellCss = string.Empty;
            bool prepend = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.TextPrepend);
            bool append = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.TextAppend);
            bool addon = prepend || append;

            if (prepend == true)
                cellCss = this.ConcatenateCss(cellCss, "input-prepend");

            if (append == true)
                cellCss = this.ConcatenateCss(cellCss, "input-append");

            if (addon == true)
            {
                int textIndex = cell.Controls.IndexOf(text);

                Literal container = new Literal();
                container.Text = "<div class=\"" + cellCss + "\">";
                cell.Controls.AddAt(textIndex, container);
            }

            if (prepend == true)
            {
                int textIndex = cell.Controls.IndexOf(text);

                Literal units = new Literal();
                units.Text = "<span class=\"add-on\">" + this.Prepend() + "</span>";
                cell.Controls.AddAt(textIndex, units);
            }

            if (append == true)
            {
                Literal units = new Literal();
                units.Text = "<span class=\"add-on\">" + this.Append() + "</span>";
                cell.Controls.Add(units);
            }

            if (addon == true)
            {
                Literal container = new Literal();
                container.Text = "</div>";
                cell.Controls.Add(container);
            }

            if (Required == true)
            {
                Literal required = new Literal();
                required.Text = "<span class=\"required\">*</span>";
                cell.Controls.Add(required);
            }

            if (HelpText != string.Empty)
            {
                Label lblHelpText = new Label();
                if (HelpDisplay == TwitterBootstrap.WebControls.TextBox.HelpTextDisplayMode.Block)
                    lblHelpText.CssClass = "help-block";
                else
                    lblHelpText.CssClass = "help-inline";
                lblHelpText.Text = HelpText;
                cell.Controls.Add(lblHelpText);
            }

            if (Required == true)
            {
                // Add a RequiredFieldValidator
                RequiredFieldValidator required = new RequiredFieldValidator();
                required.ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage;
                required.Display = ErrorDisplay;
                required.ControlToValidate = text.ID;
                required.Text = "";

                if (ValidationGroup != string.Empty)
                    required.ValidationGroup = ValidationGroup;

                cell.Controls.Add(required);
            }

            if (ValidationExpression != string.Empty)
            {
                // Add a RequiredFieldValidator
                RegularExpressionValidator regex = new RegularExpressionValidator();
                regex.ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage;
                regex.Display = ErrorDisplay;
                regex.ControlToValidate = text.ID;
                regex.ValidationExpression = ValidationExpression;

                if (ValidationGroup != string.Empty)
                    regex.ValidationGroup = ValidationGroup;

                cell.Controls.Add(regex);
            }
        }
    }

    #region Methods
    private string ConcatenateCss(params string[] classes)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        foreach (string s in classes)
            result += s + " ";

        return result.TrimEnd().TrimStart();
    }

    private static TextBox FindTextBox(Control parent)
    {
        TextBox result = null;
        foreach (Control control in parent.Controls)
        {
            if (control is TextBox)
            {
                result = control as TextBox;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected virtual string Prepend()
    {
        return this.TextPrepend;
    }

    protected virtual string Append()
    {
        return this.TextAppend;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out why this was happening. Since the `Control` collection was altered in the field, you must also override _ExtractValuesFromCell(...)`to get the`TextBox` value.

I have used a slightly altered implementation from [ASP.NET Boundfield overridden to support Dropdownlist is missing one final feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979381/asp-net-boundfield-overridden-to-support-dropdownlist-is-missing-one-final-featu) and haven't optimized for my use case. However, it works fine now.

```
public override void ExtractValuesFromCell(System.Collections.Specialized.IOrderedDictionary dictionary, DataControlFieldCell cell, DataControlRowState rowState, bool includeReadOnly)
{
    Control control = null;
    string dataField = DataField;
    object text = null;
    string nullDisplayText = NullDisplayText;
    if (((rowState & DataControlRowState.Insert) == DataControlRowState.Normal) || InsertVisible)
    {
        if (cell.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Control c in cell.Controls)
            {
                control = cell.Controls[0];

                if (c is TextBox)
                {
                    text = ((TextBox)c).Text;
                } 
            }
        }
        else if (includeReadOnly)
        {
            string s = cell.Text;
            if (s == "&nbsp;")
            {
                text = string.Empty;
            }
            else if (SupportsHtmlEncode && HtmlEncode)
            {
                text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(s);
            }
            else
            {
                text = s;
            }
        }
        if (text != null)
        {
            if (((text is string) && (((string)text).Length == 0)) && ConvertEmptyStringToNull)
            {
                text = null;
            }
            if (((text is string) && (((string)text) == nullDisplayText)) && (nullDisplayText.Length > 0))
            {
                text = null;
            }
            if (dictionary.Contains(dataField))
            {
                dictionary[dataField] = text;
            }
            else
            {
                dictionary.Add(dataField, text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```