# Custom BoundField loses control on PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, webforms, asp.net-4.5

I've implemented a simple control which renders an `abbr` tag in order to use the jQuery [TimeAgo](http://timeago.yarp.com) plugin.

```
public class TimeAgoControl : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl
{
    [Bindable(true)]
    [DefaultValue(null)]
    public string Iso8601Timestamp
    {
        get { return (string)ViewState["Iso8601Timestamp"]; }
        set { ViewState["Iso8601Timestamp"] = value; }
    }

    [Bindable(true)]
    [DefaultValue(null)]
    public override string ToolTip
    {
        get { return (string)ViewState["ToolTip"]; }
        set { ViewState["ToolTip"] = value; }
    }

    public override void RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.AddAttribute("class", "timeago");
        writer.AddAttribute("title", Iso8601Timestamp);
        writer.RenderBeginTag("abbr");
        RenderContents(writer);
        writer.RenderEndTag();
    }

    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteEncodedText(ToolTip);
    }
}
```

This works fine. I can use the above control in a `GridView TemplateField` and that also works fine:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <my:TimeAgoControl runat="server" Iso8601Timestamp='<%# Item.LastImportDate.ToString("s") %>' 
                           ToolTip='<%# Item.LastImportDate.ToString("f") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Naturally, I'd rather not have to type all of the above every time I want to use the control in a GridView, so I thought I'd abstract the above logic into a custom `BoundField` where I simply pass the name of the `DataField` containing the `DateTime` value to be rendered. Simple enough, extend from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField` and override the `InitializeDataCell` method, add a control to the `DataControlFieldCell` therein, and attach an handler to the `DataBinding` event. It works and generates the correct markup:

```
<td><abbr class="timeago" title="Wednesday, January 29, 2014 16:17">about 23 hours ago</abbr></td>
```

But when the page does a PostBack, the Control is gone and all I'm left with is

```
<td>29.01.2014 16:17:17</td>
```

Please note that **the page uses no Ajax features**: it contains no UpdatePanels nor ScriptManagers.

I've researched quite a bit, finding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338429/how-to-persist-a-control-in-a-custom-boundfield) unanswered question as well as this [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583494/custom-boundfield-doesnt-preserve-data-between-postbacks-with-added-literalcont) question which states that one must override the `ExtractValuesFromCell` method, which in my case is never called. Here's my implementation

```
public class TimeAgoBoundField : System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField
{
    protected override void InitializeDataCell(System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell cell, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlRowState rowState)
    {
        base.InitializeDataCell(cell, rowState);

        cell.Controls.Add(new TimeAgoControl());

        cell.DataBinding += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var c = (DataControlFieldCell)sender;
            //how do I get the TimeAgoControl within this scope? c.Controls.Count is 0
            var dateTimeValue = (DateTime?)DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(DataBinder.GetDataItem(c.NamingContainer), this.DataField);
            c.Controls.Add(new TimeAgoControl
            {
                Iso8601Timestamp = dateTimeValue.HasValue ? dateTimeValue.Value.ToLocalTime().ToString("s") : this.NullDisplayText,
                ToolTip = DateTimeValue.HasValue ? dateTimeValue.Value.ToLocalTime().ToString("f") : this.NullDisplayText
            });                
        };
    }
}
```

Note that if I add the control not in the `DataBind` event handler but rather in `InitializeDataCell` itself as suggested [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/AngelEyes/archive/2009/07/01/a-simple-custom-control-inheriting-from-boundfield.aspx), the `Controls` collection is **empty** (as a consequence, giving the control an ID and attempting to use `FindControl` fails returning null). Obviously the `DataBind` event is not called on postback, but given that `ViewState` is active at this stage of the lifecycle, I would have expected the control to be persisted on postback.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit overdue, but in case this helps someone, I solved this by firing up a decompiler ([DotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)) and analyzing what the base control was doing when calling `InitializeDataCell`. It turns out, this method is `protected` and is rather called in turn from the `public` method `InitializeCell` after some initialization. Additionally, it is responsible for subscribing the `OnDataBindField` method to the `DataBinding` event. Further inspection into `OnDataBindField` revealed that this method is responsible setting the `Text` property of the `TableCell`, hence why, after postback, all I was left  with was a string representation of the date.

I changed the Initialize method to `InitializeCell` and overrode the `OnDataBindField` (without calling its base counterpart) as follows:

```
public class TimeAgoBoundField : System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField
{
    public override bool ReadOnly
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override void InitializeCell(DataControlFieldCell cell, DataControlCellType cellType, DataControlRowState rowState, int rowIndex)
    {
        base.InitializeCell(cell, cellType, rowState, rowIndex);

        if (cellType == DataControlCellType.DataCell)
        {
            cell.Controls.Add(new TimeAgoControl());
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDataBindField(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is TableCell)
        {
            var cell = (TableCell)sender;
            var cellValue = this.GetValue(cell.NamingContainer);

            if (cellValue != null)
            {
                var timeAgoControl = (TimeAgoControl) cell.Controls[0];
                var dateTimeValue = (DateTime) cellValue;
                var utcDateTime = dateTimeValue.Kind != DateTimeKind.Utc ? dateTimeValue.ToUniversalTime() : dateTimeValue;
                timeAgoControl.ISO8601Timestamp = utcDateTime.ToString("s") + "Z";
            }
            else if (this.NullDisplayText != null)
            {
                cell.Text = this.NullDisplayText;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.ondatabindfield(v=vs.110).aspx) for `BoundField.OnDataBindField` now contains this note:

> **Notes to Inheritors**
>   When extending the BoundField class, you can override this method to perform a custom binding routine.